# Uneven chest by doing bench press/butterfly

Tags: push-ups, bench-press, chest

I was eager to exercise so I brought some of the dumbbells home and without anyone's help I started doing butterfly exercise or mostly known as bench press.

But this put me in a very huge dilemma. My right and left chest got uneven. I got afraid and so I quit the exercise. I am having this trouble for more than 6 months. If I do push ups the left chest gets more size and the difference still remains.

Is there a way to even out the imbalance?

Comment: Are you doing any other exercises, especially for the upper back an shoulders? How much difference is it, are other people noticing it or is it just yourself?

Comment: Well i have stop all kinds of exercises as if I do any kind of exercise the difference seems to increase. The difference is just that the left side got more stretched than the right and so if i put some force on the right chest it seems to be equal.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "butterfly exercise or mostly known as bench press." The bench press and dumbbell flies are different exercises.

Answer (score 3):

First off, Butterfly exercise and bench press are two different movements. 
The butterfly is done like [this](https://www.google.com.jm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQuAIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKw0NNlbvfY&ei=kE03UqHbBYO28wTkn4HgBg&usg=AFQjCNHoggJZ1nuqGMSmX1KJ7ijjXN3RBw&sig2=jtZVsydtVuLf7BVVBs-QMw&bvm=bv.52164340,d.eWU) and the chest press is done like [this](https://www.google.com.jm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQuAIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmB1G1K7v94&ei=sE03UsfJNo7Q9gSH1YDQDA&usg=AFQjCNEg46xzyjJHIlo68uJi4-rEx3pLsw&sig2=S4YIAocCn8S03Y6pDAXtEA&bvm=bv.52164340,d.eWU)

At any rate, the stronger side of your body will always appear to be bigger, and even if that is not your stronger side, no human being is completely symmetrical. I have an inch size difference between my right and left arm (right being bigger) and the same for my quads. Ceasing to exercise is not the answer. Continue to train, and not only train the chest, but also the shoulders and the back and arms.

Try to ensure that you so the same number of reps on either side each time (or u can do two extra on the seemingly smaller side, which is what i did to reduce a 3 inch size difference to a 1 inch size difference). Also, mix it up for the chest exercises, there is a plethora of exercises you can do to get a nice healthy chest.

Have fun!

Comment: Well i used to do butterfly that i am clear about but the difference has now become not of a inch or some thing. By wearing a shirt anyone can clearly now the difference. My left chest is like good but my right is like nothing. So i would like to know about some kind of exercise which does not involve dumbel (something like push ups) to level them.

Comment: Well as i said, work them both, but maybe do 5 extra reps on the smaller/weaker side until u get the equilibrium. One arm push ups as a great move to build on side also. So you can try doing some of those. One arm chest press and butterflies also. Train both sides, just do extra (5) on the smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, the problem may be where your muscles attach on your bones. The ones that have more leverage is stronger but have lower range of motion. If this is the issue, your smaller chest shouldn't be weaker than the other. It happens pretty commonly actually

And if this isn't the problem, It is probably a form/technique issue. Don't just do more reps on one side. That doesnt solve the issue from the source. Lower the weight, and do exercises slowly while making sure your movements are completely symmetrical. Do this until you get used to it (maybe few weeks), and slowly add some weight. as you get used to it, you'll be able to lift heavy without bending your body in a weird way.

Comment: Can you please suggest a particular type of pushups because whenever i do them my left side of the chest gets more stretched than right which shouldn't be. Please suggest.

Comment: like i said, if muscle attachment is the issue, there's nothing you can do. otherwise, just try to do everything symmetrically. there's no particular movement that will be best. If it's too hard to do symmetrically, then lower the weight. like do wall push ups